# Android Swipe to left or right?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

How can I detect in a ListView that someone swiped to the left or the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be wanting <s>[this excellent tutorial](http://androidwizard.net/2010/05/crossing-things-off-of-a-listview/)</s> (site died, here's a new link: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/09/15/crossing-things-off-lists-in-android-09-sdk/). Essentially, you're going to create a transparent view in front of the ListView which consumes horizontal motionevents and passes non-horizontal motionevents back down to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

gestures recognition wont be supported on 1.5 for which you might want to refactor gesture base code, and add to your application so to work good on 1.5 in case you are not supporting 1.5 your already good.