# Android longClickEvent and swipe event together

Tags: android

I have an activity with a ViewFliper. Also it contains GestureListener for swipe events.

ViewFlipper contains various views. One of them has multiple elements witch expect longClick.
Basicly It looks like that:

```
FlipperView
   Container
      Element1
      Element2
      Element3
```

My problem is that swipe event does not work when view "Container" is displayed. It gets consumed by longClick listener added on each "ElementX" - that is my guess - as when I remove longClickListener - swipe works perfectly.

So nothing works as it should: long click does not work as it is not a long click and swipe is not captured because of longClick.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471066/android-swipe-to-left-or-right) post has the right answer. It links to [this](http://androidwizard.net/2010/05/crossing-things-off-of-a-listview/) tutorial.

Essentially, an overlay view will consume all horizontal swipe events, and pass down the events not consumed to the view underneath. I haven't read through it fully, but hopefully it can help.