# how to handle left and right swipe

Tags: android, events

I have a listview which conatins contact numbers as it's item.

I want that when the user performs leftswipe(swap in left direction) over a contact , the app will start calling that contact.

I want to know how to handle/detect left swipe and right swipe  over a contact and how to detect on which item of list view swipe event is performed.

thanks

Comment: Refer this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/3472181/1211980 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471066/android-swipe-to-left-or-right?rq=1 question.

Answer (score 1):

there is a tutorial on handling  [Gestures in Android](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/). Check it!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onFling()` method to detect swipe and as far as detecting a swipe for a particula list itme is considered, you will have to provide your own `adapter` and override it's `getView()` method.
 For eg

```
public class My_simple_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> //THIS IS THE CUSTOM ADAPTER
{
 private final Context context;
 private final String[] values;

 public My_simple_adapter(Context context,String[] values,int[] pos)
 {
  super(context,R.layout.list_item,values);
  this.context=context;
  this.values=values;

 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position,View convert_view,ViewGroup parent)
 {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MY_LAYTOUT, parent, false);
   // THE ABOVE MY_LAYOUT IS THE LAYOUT YOU WANT TO LOAD FOR EACH ROW OF THE LISTVIEW
  TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
  textView.setText(values[position]);

  //SUPPOSE rlt IS THE ID OF THE ABOVE MY_LAYOUT
  //then
  rlt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
         {
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("test", "clicked!");
                    if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))  {
                        Log.d("test", "gesture detected");
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

  return  rowView;
 }
}
```

This is the **gestureDetector** :

```
 SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener
       = new SimpleOnGestureListener(){
  @Override
     public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
       float velocityY) {
                boolean result;
              //DECIDE UNDER WHAT SPEED OF SWIPING U WANT TO MAKE THE CALL
                ...
                ...
           return result;
     }

  @Override
  public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
  {

     return true;
  }

       };
//AND FINALLY

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector
           = new GestureDetector(simpleOnGestureListener);
```